# Choosing which figures to show on-screen and which to save to a file using Python's matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to create different figures in Python using `matplotlib.pyplot`. I'd then like to save some of them to a file, while others should be shown on-screen using the `show()` command.

However, `show()` displays *all* created figures. I can avoid this by calling `close()` after creating the plots which I don't want to show on-screen, like in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = [4, 2, 7, 3]
y2 = [-7, 0, -1, -3]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(y1)
plt.savefig('figure1.png')
plt.close()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(y2)

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

This saves the first figure and shows the second one. However, I get an error message:

> can't invoke "event" command:  application has been destroyed while executing

Is it possible to select in a more elegant way which figures to show?

Also, is the first `figure()` command superfluous? It doesn't seem to make a different whether I give it or not.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way is to use `plt.clf()` instead of `plt.close()`.
Moreover `plt.figure()` creates a new graph while you can just clear previous one with `plt.clf()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = [4, 2, 7, 3]
y2 = [-7, 0, -1, -3]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(y1)
plt.savefig('figure1.png')
plt.clf()

plt.plot(y2)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

This code will not generate errors or warnings such can't invoke "event" command...

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you can just close the figure.  As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10), 'ro-')
plt.title('This figure will be saved but not shown')
fig1.savefig('fig1.png')
plt.close(fig1)

fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10), 'bo')
plt.title('This figure will be shown')

plt.show()
```

As far as whether or not the first `plt.figure()` call is superflous, it depends on what you're doing.  Usually, you want to hang on to the figure object it returns and work with that instead of using matplotlib's matlab-ish state machine interface.

When you're making more complex plots, it often becomes worth the extra line of code to do something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(range(10))
```

The advantage is that you don't have to worry about which figure or axis is "active", you just refer to a specific axis or figure object.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, Joe.

However, similar to my code, this gives the following error message:

can't invoke "event" command:  application has been destroyed
    while executing
"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
    (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
    invoked from within
"ttk::ThemeChanged"

Comment: @gandi2223 - Can you post the full traceback? That should be generating an error...

Comment: Hmm, what exactly do you mean by full traceback? I had a look at http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: @gandi2223 - Just the full text of what it spits out. It will have the exact line that generated the error, the line that called that line, etc all the way back up the stack.  It may be easier to use pastebin or something similar, if it's too much text to cram into a comment.  (Also, I meant "shouldn't" rather than "should" in my comment above! Remind me to read things after I type them! :) )

Comment: Well, when I execute the script I've posted above (on 23 May) in a terminal window, all I get is this:
can't invoke "event" command:  application has been destroyed
    while executing
"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
    (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
    invoked from within
"ttk::ThemeChanged"

Comment: I figure the problem is that I'm closing the first plot, and then - after having created the second one - Python wants to show and close all plots. I assume it struggles because the first plot has been closed already. Does that make sense?

Comment: @gandi2223 - Ah, that's a TK warning, rather than a python error.  You should be able to safely ignore it (everything seems to run perfectly).  It didn't happen on older version of matplotlib and/or TK (which is why I couldn't reproduce it before. I've upgraded things since, and I get the same warning.). It's presumably a bug, but it appears to only be a warning. Everything still seems to work...

Comment: @Joe - yes, everything seems to work fine, I get the visual output of the plot as desired, and the other plot is saved. I was just wondering if the warning was a problem. But if it's not actually my code that is dogdy, then I'm happy to ignore the warning! :-) Thanks!