# How to surpress can't invoke "event" command: application

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm aware that this has been discussed several times, but the solutions don't seem to fit my case. The closest is:
[Choosing which figures to show on-screen and which to save to a file using Python's matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093504/choosing-which-figures-to-show-on-screen-and-which-to-save-to-a-file-using-pytho)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = [4, 2, 7, 3]
y2 = [-7, 0, -1, -3]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(y1)
plt.savefig('figure1.png')
plt.close()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(y2)

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

And as already mentioned this produces an

```
can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed while executing
```

when run as a script. The accepted solution though is to only generate one figure, and not close it but rather clear it with `plt.clf()`

But in my case I will have multiple figures. I do not want to overwrite them. This would be a big mess, so how can i properly close a figure and not get the **can't invoke event command** error.

## Update

As it was pointed out, this is not a real problem/error in such that the code works fine. So ultimately it should be enough to just suppress the error message.

Comment: What you get is not an error, but a warning. I suppose the script is otherwise working as expected? (This is also mentionned in [the comment below one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093504/choosing-which-figures-to-show-on-screen-and-which-to-save-to-a-file-using-pytho#comment7532248_6105481)) If so, is this question about suppressing the warning?

Comment: Well now that I think about it year that might be enough